# Have mocked request throw error by status code only

Tags: python, python-requests, mocking, python-unittest

I'm writing some unit tests where I mock out requests to another service. Here's the method I'm testing.

```
def ping_camera(self, camera):
    retry_ping = Retry(
        total=3,
        status_forcelist=[404, 429, 500, 502, 503, 504],
        method_whitelist=["GET"],
        backoff_factor=1,
    )
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry_ping)
    http = requests.Session()
    http.mount("http://", adapter)

    try:
        response = http.get("http://{}".format(camera.ip_address), timeout=3)
        response.raise_for_status()
    except Exception as e:
        camera.camera_status = False
        camera.save()
    else:
        camera.camera_status = True
        camera.save()
```

And here's one of my tests.

```
@patch.object(Session, "get")
def test_expects_true_camera_status_to_return_false_status(self, mock):
    # Arrange
    mock.side_effect = Exception

    # Act
    check_cams = CheckCameras()
    check_cams.ping_camera(self.camera)
    
    # Assert
    self.assertFalse(self.camera.camera_status)
```

Note that in order to have an exception raised, I need to add `mock.side_effect = Exception`. I come from the Laravel world where only the response status needs to be specified and if a bad response is returned, an exception will be raised.

I can even specify a good response, and still trigger an exception like so

```
    mock.return_value.status_code = 200
    mock.side_effect = Exception
```

Is this just a quirk of a Python testing, or can I have exceptions raised based off the response status code alone?

Meaning if I add `mock.return_value.status_code = 500` I'll get an exception raised and hit the `except` portion of my code block.

Comment: If you specify a `side_effect` then the `return_value` is irrelevant. More broadly this is just _how testing works_, the boundary you're mocking at has the API of throwing an error in the case you want to test. If you want a non-2xx status to become an error, you need to move the boundary _behind_ the code (presumably somewhere within requests) that does that.

Comment: I understand that the `side_effect` overrules the `return_value` but this seems wrong. Again, coming from Laravel testing, the response status dictates the outcome, just like in the real world. I don't understand why Python wouldn't use this same principle.

Comment: _"the response status dictates the outcome"_ - that would be true if the code that was responsible for that was involved in your test, but you've **explicitly mocked it out**. You're not comparing like with like, presumably you aren't testing at the same boundary in Laravel. This is nothing to do with Python and PHP having different principles, rather with you doing different things. Maybe you're expecting something more like https://pypi.org/project/responses/?

Comment: I get what you're saying but there is a distinct difference between Laravel testing and python testing. Just take a look at the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#testing). I can mock the Http client and then mock the response status which does in fact dictate the outcome. That's what I'm trying to replicate with my python tests.

Comment: No, there isn't. There's a difference between _the test doubles_, Laravel's presumably has more behaviour (and is therefore arguably a less good test double). If you want your Python test double to throw an error based on the response status, you need to _write that code_. But the behaviour of the code you're testing is based on the fact that its collaborator throws an error, **not** that the status this represents is non-2xx.